Python Setuptools ModuleNotFoundError When Importing Another Pip Package
I am trying to build a wheel/sdist with setuptools, it is giving me an error when one of my scripts imports bs4 (beautifulsoup4).
Here is what it displays after running python3 -m build:
* Creating venv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools >= 40.8.0)
* Getting build dependencies for sdist...

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist

This is what is it detecting as an error:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Here is my setup.py:
import setuptools
import mypackage

def readme():
    with open("README.md", 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version=mypackage.__version__,
    author=mypackage.__author__,
    maintainer=mypackage.__author__,
    description=mypackage.__description__,
    long_description=readme(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license=mypackage.__license__,
    python_requires=">=3.10",
    install_requires=[
        "beautifulsoup4",
    ],
)

This is stressful :/
Versions
setuptools version: 69.0.3
Python version: 3.11.8

To resolve this error, you need to install the beautifulsoup4 library using pip as shown below:
pip install beautifulsoup4

For pip3:
pip3 install beautifulsoup4

Once the module is installed, you should be able to run the code that imports bs4 without receiving this error.

I'm aware of this, I just found a way to build it via python3 -m build -n (which is no isolation [which was almost certainly the issue]), I already had these installed which didn't work prior to finding out python3 -m build -n would work.

I found a way to build it, you have to build it without an isolated environment, e.g.: python3 -m build -n, and after that you can install it inside your own virtual environment that you created via python -m venv .venv. Still curious if anyone else has another way, or if I just have to use python -m build -n every time.
